# Is there a way to get the current browser name using selenium web-driver (nodejs)?

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I tried doing driver.getBroswerName(), but it didnt recognize the function getBrowerName()?. I guess there is not that function. So is there any other way to get the current browser name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
driver.getCapabilities().then(function (caps) {
    console.log(caps.get("browserName"));
});
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCapabilities' of undefined -- still getting the same error. And some articles say that they remove that functionalities in newer version of selenium-webdriver. So it cant be access like that anymore: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/CHANGES.md#v2520\

Comment: If you feel the issue is resolved, please accept the answer by clicking on the hallow check mark below the down vote button.